# Coercive bilinear form satisfying $Az=\Phi'(z)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space, $A$ compact such that there exist $\alpha$ with
$<Au,u>  \ge \alpha||u||^2$ $\forall u $ (i.e coercive)
Let $\Phi \in C^1(X, \mathbb{R})$ such that $\Phi$ satisfies
$lim_{||u|| \to \infty}\frac{|\Phi(u)|}{||u||^2}=0$
Assume that $\Phi$ is weakly continuous. I want to show there exist $z \in X$ such that $Az=\Phi'(z)$

I'm not really sure where to start. I don't see how the assumptions lead to conclusion, any nudge in the right direction would be appreciated

Comment: A compact operator cannot be coercive on infinite-dimensional spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is self-adjoint then you should be able to show existence of solutions for
$$
\min_u \frac 12\langle Au,u\rangle - \Phi(u).
$$
Every solution $z$ of this problem then satisfies $Az=\Phi'(z)$.

(Compactness is not needed here)

Comment: I see that your functional  $I(u)$ has a minimum. $I'(z)=0$ gets us what we want but how did you come up with that functional and where is self adjointness used? Where is coerciveness and thye other hypothesis of the problem used ?

Comment: Self-adjointness is used to get $Az$ as derivative (otherwise the derivative would be $(A+A^*)z/2$.

Comment: The other conditions are used to prove that level sets of the functional are bounded (and hence weakly sequentially compact).

Comment: So this was a trivial problem huh?

Comment: can you tell me motivation behind find this specific functional?

Comment: About motivation: the conditions you gave (coercivity and properties of $\Phi$) reminded me of proofs of existence of solutions of minimization problems. Then I came up with the functional above, whose derivative is as in the desired equation.